# SQL Azure readonly user who cannot delete database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I've created a readonly user ala:

```
(in master)
CREATE LOGIN reader WITH password='YourPWD';
CREATE USER readerUser FROM LOGIN reader;

(in target db)
CREATE USER readerUser FROM LOGIN reader;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'readerUser';
```

This works well in denying the user access to do anything but read from tables in the target db.

However it still allows them to delete the target db from management studio.

How can I deny them db deletion rights?

Answer (score 3):

Can you clarify what you mean by DB deletion rights? Do you mean DROP the database? If so, the permission for DROP DATABASE is in master. So ensure that the login is not part of the dbmanager role.

If you meant deleting data from tables then by default users in database do not have that permission unless you add them in roles like db_datawriter or db_owner or grant DELETE permission explicitly.

You can check permissions of user by doing something like:

```
execute as user = 'readerUser';
select * from fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE');
revert;
go
```